# What is precise mathematical definition?

Tags: real-analysis

For X cadlag and has finite quadratic variation (QV), the value in the money market account is given by 
$Y_t=-X_tS(t,0)+\int_{t}^{0} X_{u-} dS(u,0)-\int_{t}^{0} S_x^{(1)}(u-,0)d[X,X]_u^c-\sum_{0\leq u\leq t}[S(u,\bigtriangleup X_u)-S(u,0)]\bigtriangleup X_u$
What $X_{u-}$ and $S_x^{(1)}(u-,0)$ whith (u-) mean?

Comment: See [Càdlàg function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A0dl%C3%A0g) : left limit vs right limit.

Comment: Usually they denote the left limit.